# Implementing a system call for CPU hotplug on RPI3/ModelB

Tags: pi-3, linux, kernel, archlinux

My goal is to implement a system call in linux kernel that enables/disables a CPU core.

First, I implemented a system call that disbales CPU3 in a 4-core system.

The system call code is as follows:

```c
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>
#include <asm/uaccess.h>
#include <asm/unistd.h>
#include <linux/cpumask.h>
#include <linux/smp.h>

asmlinkage long sys_new_syscall(void)
{
    unsigned int cpu3 = 3;

    set_cpu_online (cpu3, false) ;          /* clears the CPU in the cpumask */
    printk ("CPU%u is offline\n", cpu3);


    return 0;
}
```

The system call was registered correctly in the kernel and I enabled  'cpu hotplug' feature during kernel configuration ( See picture )
[Kernel configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgQoG.jpg)

The kernel was build . But when I check the system call using test.c :

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <unistd.h>



long new_syscall(void)
{
    return syscall(394);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     long int a = new_syscall();
     printf("System call returned %ld\n", a);
     return 0;
}
```

The OS frezzes ! 
What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: You're sure that's the correct syscall number?

Comment: yes sure the syscall number is correct.